# How to configure the yml files for Elasticsearch when hosted on a server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, yaml, elastic-stack

I am trying to host an Elasticsearch application on an aws server.

I was able to experiment with it and make it work, but it is incredibly unstable and crashes the AWS machine. However, this happens only, when I start enterprise-search after elasticsearch. I am pretty sure, that I still haven't configured the yml files correctly. Can someone please take a look?

Here are the relevant information:

```
Private DNS: ip-172-31-14-57.eu-central-1.compute.internal
Private IPs: 172.31.14.57
Public DNS (IPv4): ec2-3-122-100-12.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
IPv4 Public IP: 3.122.100.12
```

The elasticsearch.yml looks currently as follows:

```
network.host: ec2-3-122-100-12.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["ec2-18-194-234-6.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9300"]

xpack.security.enabled: false
discovery.type: single-node
cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled: true
xpack.security.authc.api_key.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
```

I had to turn `xpack.security.enabled` off for the moment, because it produced an error. But I guess it's not related to the problem

The enterprise-search.yml looks as follows:

```
secret_management.encryption_keys: [5322b64cf4260f9d94751a471e5921829f3b83cda9f..]
ent_search.auth.source: standard
allow_es_settings_modification: true
elasticsearch.host: http://ec2-3-122-100-12.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9200
elasticsearch.username: elastic
elasticsearch.password: 9Xyj4hECTcih...
ent_search.external_url: http://ec2-3-122-100-12.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws:3002
ent_search.listen_host: 3.122.100.12
ent_search.listen_port: 3002
```

Could someone please have a look and see what I am doing wrong? I would appreciate a lot, I ve spent countless hours trying to fix this whole projects.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Could you please share the logs of Elasticsearch when the crash incident happens. It might give some more clues.

Comment: the AWS machine just stops responding and I eventually have to restart it

Comment: Do you see spike in resource consumption like RAM/CPU ? That could explain the reason why the VM is "freezing".

Comment: | the AWS machine just stops responding and I eventually have to restart it
Perhaps take a look at the system logs to see if you can grep for error or something to find out the cause of it being stuck.